# Transforming one column in an list of dicts

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I would like to transform one column in my Excel in a list of dictionaries. Is it possible?

Input sample:

```
A     B      C      D      E
0.00  10.00  22.00  10.00  15.00
1.00  81.29  28.00  23.33  18.38
```

Output sample:

```
somefunc(column="A")
[{ "A": 0.00 }, { "A": 1.00 }]
```

Currently i'm using this code, and then deleting the extra keys.. which doesn't make sense at all.

```
def to_dict(file_path, header_index=0, sheet_index=0):
    data, keys, sheet = {}, [], _read(file_path).sheet_by_index(sheet_index)
    for col_index in xrange(0, sheet.ncols):
        keys.append(sheet.cell(header_index, col_index).value.encode("utf-8"))
    for row_index in xrange(2, sheet.nrows):
        for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols):
            if keys[col_index] not in data.keys():
                data[keys[col_index]] = []
            data[keys[col_index]].append(sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value)
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
def to_dict(file_path, header_index=0, sheet_index=0):
    result = []
    sheet = _read(file_path).sheet_by_index(sheet_index)
    for row_index in xrange(2, sheet.nrows):
        row_dict = {}
        for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols):
            key = sheet.cell(header_index, col_index).value.encode("utf-8")
            row_dict[key] = sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value
        result.append(row_dict)
    return result
```